# Unable to Export to Excel

Tags: 2013, excel, export, internet-explorer

I am attempting to export a list of files and their metadata into excel 2010 via internet explorer, the file is created and appears to download normally but when opening the excel window it freezes when the status bar on the bottom of the window shows "Connecting to datasource".

Is there a change needed in the internet settings or is it simply a version mismatch issue?

Comment: What's the type of IE ? are you tried to use Google chrome ?!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Internet Explorer are you using?  This functionality works fine for me on IE 11 (in and out of compatibility mode).  Also, are you using the List tab in the ribbon and the "Export to Excel" option there?

Its possible it is also an issue with the number of rows you're exporting, how many items are in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have already added the site URL to compatibility view and local intranet sites, if it is not working , try to use another browser ! to make sure that the problem is not related to sharepoint